# Spring ws security header Unknown password type encoding exception

Tags: spring-ws

I am implementing spring Wss4jSecurityInterceptor to generate SOAP envelope wsse header , want to include plain password text , but unfortunately i am getting **Unknown password type encoding**  , don't see any options to disable the encoding type . Please find the below code snippet and exception details and help.

```
@Bean
    public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor(){
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN +" "+ WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP);
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("scott");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("tiger");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsernameTokenCreated(true);
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsernameTokenNonce(true);

        return wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
    }
```

> org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecuritySecurementException: Unknown password type encoding: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText; nested exception is org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Unknown password type encoding: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText
>       at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.secureMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:577) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:210) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:597) [spring-ws-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) [spring-ws-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) [spring-ws-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at com.bcbsfl.ais.medical.records.AISClient.getMedicalRecords(AISClient.java:144) [bin/:na]
>       at com.bcbsfl.ais.medical.records.SpringBootSoapClientApplication.lookup(SpringBootSoapClientApplication.java:21) [bin/:na]
>       at com.bcbsfl.ais.medical.records.SpringBootSoapClientApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd3ea8fc.CGLIB$lookup$0() [bin/:na]
>       at com.bcbsfl.ais.medical.records.SpringBootSoapClientApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd3ea8fc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ec9388da.invoke() [bin/:na]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at com.bcbsfl.ais.medical.records.SpringBootSoapClientApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd3ea8fc.lookup() [bin/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>       at com.bcbsfl.ais.medical.records.SpringBootSoapClientApplication.main(SpringBootSoapClientApplication.java:14) [bin/:na]
>   Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Unknown password type encoding: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText
>       at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.decodeUTParameter(WSHandler.java:509) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>       at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:141) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
>       at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jHandler.doSenderAction(Wss4jHandler.java:63) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.secureMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:574) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]

Comment: Issue got resolved  WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT builiding text as http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText;  instead of PasswordText . So password the string directly xml built as expected

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved  WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT builiding text as http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText;  instead of PasswordText . So passed the string directly and xml built as expected

instead of `wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);`

replaced with `wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType("PasswordText");`

Comment: It didn't resolve it for me. When I did that it gave
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Unknown password type encoding: http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText

Comment: Use WsConstants.PW_TEXT, which is "PasswordText".